# singleton list hasn't been re-initialized until restart IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql, singleton, initialization

I have a problem about a singleton list inside my asp.net website. Based on design, the singleton list is used to store all the customized information, so the first user access the website and the singleton list is called, if it is empty then it will be initialized (call a select sql script and fetch data from database).

Then on a backend site, we have a page which is used to clear all the data inside the singleton list, which is used only when we update some customized information in database.

This logic is clear and used to work fine. However, yesterday I just added a new customized record, and then after I cleared the singleton list, I still couldn't see the new added customized info. I try many times, it just didn't work. So I did the same thing on our test environment, it worked perfect.  At last, I occasionally try command **iisreset** , it started working. I mean this was weird, and I tried to figure out why, can someone give me some clue? Very appreciate it.

Comment: cause this weird thing happened only once during the past 2 months, and it used to work fine, we reinitialized the list many times, all good, only this time failed, i didn't get some clue to think why, and I use lock when reinitialize it,

Answer (score 0):

There are some configuration changes that require IIS to be restarted before they will be committed.  I make it a habit and it's pretty standard practice to restart IIS after making changes to something that's done on startup or init.

Basically, it's not unusual to have to do this.  Don't worry about it unless it's not being rebuilt or something like that but if it's getting built when it should then that's a good thing.

Here is a link to the [IIS](http://www.iis.net) site.

Comment: Where did the OP say anything about configuration changes? They have a singleton list (code - not config) which is being wiped, but not having the new data inserted. There's nothing in there about configuration. And even if so - updating the `web.config` file, for example, automatically restarts the site to load the changes.

Comment: few seconds ago that crossed my mind after your question. you are right I have edited my answer.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't need any web.config change, the only thing the code does is clear list->recall a sql-script and refill the list, that is it.

Answer (score 0):

May be in the direction of application isolation mode or totally a different issue in your code. For application isolation mode.
Please read [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true).

I am looking at application isolation level in IIS on a few judgments made on the comments  from the OP.

- 1.) Once the application changed and deployed on test server and production server it is assumed that the application was re-started
- 2.) In production environment it did not work but in test environment it worked
- 3.) But in production environment it worked once the IIS re-started

Given the above 3 facts it would have suspected application isolation has been changed in production environment ever since the last application update had been made to the production (based on OP's additional comments)
I may be totally wrong but assumption is logical.

Comment: How did you get this idea from the question?

Comment: wasn't it that application restart did not initialize the singleton but iis restart did?

Comment: No; the OP never said anything about an app restart (which probably would have worked, too). Their code was failing to reinitialize the list. This question almost certainly can't be answered without seeing that code, which is likely faulty somehow.

Comment: A few seconds ago that crossed my mind after your question. you may be right I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the code worked fine, cause the logic is very clear, and it works in our test environment and also worked fine during the past 2 months and have reinitialized the singleton list many times cause we updated the customizable fields often, only this time failed.